# "A Quasi-Catch-22"?; phrase request for having to "oversolve" a problem

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

It's a bit difficult to explain exactly what I'm getting at, so I'll give an example:

If I get on the bus for work at 8:00 (having to be there at 9:00), there will be a traffic jam and it will take an hour and a half to get there, making me late. However, if I leave for work at 7:30, an hour and a half before I need to be at work, there will be no traffic jam and it will only take forty-five minutes to get there, so I'll arrive at work earlier than I need to. Let's assume for the sake of the question that:

- there is no middle ground (If I leave any later than 7:30, the bus will be caught in a traffic jam and I will be late; if I leave at 7:30 or earlier, I will arrive much earlier than is necessary.)
- arriving early is not a bad thing (i.e. a "neutral"/acceptable outcome)

Is there a phrase/expression for this situation that is reminiscent of a Catch-22 or the expression "damned if you do, damned if you don't," but differs in that rather than <strike>the solution renders itself unnecessary (without</strike> creating any negative consequences, the solution simply "oversolves" the problem?

### Update:

1 - When I originally posted, I think the bus example drew focus away from the real core of the question, so I wanted to add one more (brief) example. Say you're at the supermarket buying hot dogs and buns. The buns only come in packages of six, and the hot dogs only come in packages of eight. To have enough buns, you'll have to buy a second package, but then you'll be left with more buns than you need. (Note to pedants: Assume you're specifically planning to feed eight people and they all definitely only want one hot dog each.)
2 - I think two of the existing answers--"necessary overkill" and "inescapable overcompensation"--are excellent and come quite close, but I'd like to see if there is some other idiomatic, "on-the-nose" phrase for this kind of situation.

Comment: Take a train? Ride into work? Buy a moped! Just kidding. The *lesser of two evils* would be my choice, if you consider going to work an evil.

Comment: How about "doomed to be late"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ha! If only EL&U could address life issues the way it does English issues. _Lesser of two evils_ is on the right track, but I'm wondering if there's something for a) the solution/action eliminating the need for itself, and b) the neutrality/lack of negative consequences in the resulting outcome. (For the question, and _only_ for the question, I'm considering arriving early at work as not being evil.) ^_^

Comment: Why do you think "damned if you are, and damn if you're not" doesn't fit. You take the 7 o'clock bus you arrive too early. Take the 8 o'clock bus you get to work late. I used to have this problem when I lived out in the sticks in Italy, a small village which had something like only five buses running a day to the city centre.

Comment: @Mari-LouA As an aside, this is why I tend to bike into work, especially on Mondays. But again, for the sake of the question and the expression I'm trying to come up with, the "early to work" bit is not considered a negative outcome. Since you ask, I'm starting to think I should be focusing more on the "elimination" part of the situation. I'm gonna rephrase the question a bit to try to make this more apparent.

Comment: I think I understand the situation - one whose solution necessitates overkill - but I'm not sure why you describe it as "solution renders itself unnecessary." Leaving at 7:30 seems necessary as part of the rules you yourself set up.

Comment: Petition the transit company to add a 7:45 bus (or whenever it will get you there on time; there has to be a nearer solution). Until such time, you have a discontiguous solution set to your problem. But if getting there early is not an issue, why not take the 6: 30 bus—or the 5:30 bus?  If you get there before everbody else does, nobody can complain when you leave early, because for all they know, you did put in a full day's work.

Comment: Yes, I'm having trouble finding the best way to express that. What I mean to say is:

I must be at work at 9:00.
Leaving at 8:00, it takes 90 minutes to reach work due to traffic. (problem)
Leaving 90 minutes before work (at 7:30), it only takes 30 minutes to arrive at work. (solution)

The "solution" of leaving 90 minutes early means, in a sense, that I don't actually have to leave 90 minutes early, because I will arrive at 8:00.
But if I leave any later, there'll be heavy traffic and I will be late.

The solution is necessary, but applying it simultaneously negates the problem it addressed.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Though it's close to real-life experience, this is just an example to illustrate the situation I'm trying to find an expression for. There are most likely other non-time-related examples out there.

Comment: So, don't catch the 22. Catch the 38, then transfer to the 17 at Wabash.  That'll get you there on time. You just have to be able to think outside the box, or you'll be stuck in that box forever (or not, like Schroedinger's cat.)

Comment: Perhaps "Worse is the right thing" or "Worse is the solution" ?

Comment: You are a victim of Murphy's Law.  "If anything can go wrong, it will."  Sometimes phrased as "Murphy's Law always wins."   It seems to me that your only choice is to decide how to use the extra 45 min at work.

Comment: At least as far as your example goes - wouldn't almost any bus bring you to work either early or late? It would be more unusual if there were a bus that brought you there precisely on time.

Comment: Wait, is it perhaps about the relationship between the *extent* of the difference in leaving vs arriving times? For instance, normally in a situation like this, if you leave a half hour earlier, you would expect to get there a half hour earlier. But in this case, leaving a half hour earlier gets you there a whole hour earlier. *Necessary inconsistency* between leaving and arriving time differences. Getting warmer?

Comment: @MishaRosnach For that specific example, that's getting closer. But it still seems people are getting hung up on the example with buses and lateness. That was only meant to illustrate the idea. I'm still trying to think up an additional example not related to time. Sven's answer might be the closest way of expressing this that there can be. Perhaps the solution is "oversolving" the problem rather than "negating the need for itself" as I originally phrased it in my question.

Comment: Instead of "[over]solving the problem", you may "skirt the issue", i.e. find a workaround..

Answer (score 3):

I would use the phrase "necessary overkill" to describe your approach to handling this situation. Arriving at work 45 minutes before your workday officially begins is *overkill* in sense 2 of the definition of that word that appears in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **overkill** *n* (1958) **1 :** a destructive capacity greatly exceeding that required for  given target **2 :** an excess of something (as a quantity or an action) beyond what is required or suitable for a particular purpose {publicity *overkill*} (an *overkill* in weaponry} **3 :** killing in excess of what is intended or required

If "on-timeness" is the something that is required, and if arriving at the office at 9:00 a.m. constitutes being on time, then being at the office at 8:15 a.m. every day constitutes overkill because it is 45 minutes in excess of (that is, earlier than) what is objectively required to satisfy the condition for on-timeness.

However, since the only way to avoid failing to meet the requirement of on-timeness is to take the overkill route of leaving for work at 7:30 a.m. each morning, that route is necessary, not optional. Hence, *necessary overkill*.

Here are three examples of the phrase in action. From [*Mennonite Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=22tCAQAAIAAJ&q=%22necessary+overkill%22&dq=%22necessary+overkill%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwBDgKahUKEwj3_rrFlubHAhUSKogKHesxCDM), volume 34 (1979) [combined snippets], we have an example of *necessary overkill* involving sense 1 of the word:

> Senator Barry Goldwater, upon hearing that President Carter had approved proceeding with the M-X Missile System, responded by saying that it was "**necessary overkill**." John Cox has written a book, first published in the U.S in 1978, in which he contends that the present trend to seek overkill is folly.

And from [*Gargoyle Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LDSxAAAAIAAJ&q=%22necessary+overkill%22&dq=%22necessary+overkill%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAzgKahUKEwj3rqPLl-bHAhUDo4gKHdwbADk), issue 27 (1985) [combined snippets]. we have this example involving sense 2 of the phrase, from an interview with Rita Dove:

> **Interviewer:** I think that's a recent change. I think we've gotten away from the 60's when people said you have to write what you know.
>
> **Dove:** It was a time of, I think, **necessary overkill**, especially in terms of black literature—a time when, in order to develop black consciousness, it was important to stress blackness, to make sure the poems talked about being black. 'Cause it had never really been talked about before—it wasn't predominant, except in the Harlem Renaissance, sure, but then we had, in a certain way, forgotten about that. So I think it was necessary and the pendulum had swung back.

And finally, from [*Tempo: Indonesia's Weekly News Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=3dETAQAAMAAJ&q=%22necessary+overkill%22&dq=%22necessary+overkill%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCWoVChMIg87xjprmxwIVVjaICh3zxwxI) (2005):

> JK's style is different from SBY's. Running a government often calls for special policies. In order to effectively solve problems, the steps to be taken cannot be halfhearted; if necessary they may come with a high cost and sacrifice, forcing some **necessary overkill**. This is where the difference between JK and SBY is apparent.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term *overcompensation* can be flexibly used for this one.

Now, to use that in a sentence for the bus example (sorry, but it is a pretty good example), I think the conversation with a coworker might go something like this:

"So, normally this takes about 15 minutes, but traffic starts right after 8.  Next earliest is 7:30 and no traffic, a bit of an inescapable overcompensation here. Ah well."

Answer (score 0):

If being late for work is unacceptable and out of the question, then you have a *Hobson's Choice*: You can choose to take whatever transportation method gets you to work on time. You just happen to have only one choice available, the one that gets you there very early.

P.S. "The solution is necessary, but applying it simultaneously negates the problem it addressed."  That is not clear at all. Let's say a person cannot swim and must cross a river. Boats are nowhere to be found, there are no fallen logs to float on, and he has no axe to chop down a tree.  He must wait until winter when the river freezes over.  The problem (he will sink and drown) has been negated by waiting for the ice. Aren't problems always negated by their solutions?

Comment: I probably need to think some more on how to phrase that so it's clearer. I was trying to differentiate there between an action solving the problem and eliminating/removing the source of the problem. And it seems I need to change the example as well, as everyone seems to be focusing on the specifics it lays out, rather than the general concept.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the "real" solution for the man who has to cross the river is to learn how to swim? Learning how to swim removes the "source" of his problem?